# How can i query the data in a sub-document of a document from a sub-document of another document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my category schema. For every category document, there is a subdocument of subcategories

```
#category schema
const CategorySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String, required: true
    },
    subcategories: [{
        name: {
            type: String, required: false
        },
    }],
    created : {
        type : Date,
        default: Date.now()
    }
});

let Categories = mongoose.model('categories', CategorySchema);
```

```
# selected category schema

const BusinessCategoriesSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    business_id: {
        type: String
    },
    category_id: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "categories",
        required: true
    },
    subcategories: [{
        subcategory_id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "subcategories._id",
            required: false
        }
    }]
});

let businessCategories = mongoose.model('business-categories', BusinessCategoriesSchema);
```

How can I retrieve the `subcategories` sub-document from `Categories` schema when I perform a query on `business-categories` collection?

```
#This is the code snippet I am using but am not getting my desired result

const query = await businessCategories.find({business_id : businessId })
.populate('category_id')
.populate('subcategories.subcategories_id');
```

I know I am not doing something right.

I was able to get the category name from `categories` schema but I could not get the `subcategories` sub-document from the `categories` schema.

Thank you in advance